# RegEx Matching the 8th URL of an Email String

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a specific URL String in an email and I am currently able to find the first URL String with no problem but after that, I lose it.

```
https?\:\/\/[^\"]+
```

Comment: Your regex ends in a `[^\"]+`, matching every character except `"`. This means that the remainder of your email will be caught, until a `"` is found - it won't end capturing at the end of your URL (unless your URL is guaranteed to end in `"`). Other than that, how are you capturing your groups? Using `re.findall()` you should be able to find all matches of your RegEx, and then simply pick the 8th from the results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the `re.findall` function. It return a list with all the matching regex. The one I used was just an example. Then, you can just look to the 8th URL:

```py
r = requests.get('https://github.com/')
print(r)
r = "".join(r.text.split('\n'))

txt = re.findall('https?:\/\/.[\w\d.\/_-]+', r)
print(txt[7])
```